# Right mouse click in visual studio 2012 hanging

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In Visual Studio 2012, I have noticed that when I use the right mouse button for the context menu, it takes between 10 and 20 seconds before the menu appears...This has only been a recent issue.  I have tried resetting all of the VS settings, uninstalling and reinstalling VS, repairing VS...everything short of wiping the computer and starting over...I have also noticed that some of my shortcuts...ie, "Go To Declaration", are now disabled and I can't use them...

All help is greatly appriciated.